# Instantiating of a generic collection class c#

Tags: c#, generics, instantiation

learn.microsoft.com: "Because a generic type definition is only a template, **you cannot create instances of a class**, structure, or interface **that is a generic type definition**." so how come I can write this: `Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();` or it is not an **instantiation?** so what am I doing then?

Comment: Quote appears to come from the first bullet in the list of Generics terminology in [this part of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/#generics-terminology).

Comment: `Dictionary<,>` is a generic type.  `Dictionary<int, string>` has defined all the generic template parts, and is no longer generic.

Comment: @Neil: `Dictionary<int, string>` is also a generic type, just not a generic type *definition*, which `Dictionary<,>` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an instanciation. When you do
`Dictionary<int, string> d =  new Dictionary<int, string>()`, you instanicate `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` with `TKey : int`  and `TValue : string`.

What you cannot do is `Dictionary d = new Dictionary()` which should return the error you are describing.

Answer (score 4):

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/#generics-terminology) are referring to the so called open generic types. I.e. you can't instantiate `Dictionary<,>`, you need to provide both generic type parameters, which results in so called closed (or constructed) generic type (i.e. `Dictionary<int, string>` in your case) which can be instantiated.

From [Open and closed types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#843-open-and-closed-types) docs:

> All types can be classified as either open types or closed types. An open type is a type that involves type parameters. More specifically:
>
> - A type parameter defines an open type.
> - An array type is an open type if and only if its element type is an open type.
> - A constructed type is an open type if and only if one or more of its type arguments is an open type. A constructed nested type is an open type if and only if one or more of its type arguments or the type arguments of its containing type(s) is an open type.

> A closed type is a type that is not an open type.